# Не отображается STATIC WinAPI

Tags: winapi, ассемблер, masm32

Господа, доброго времени суток! Подскажите, почему у меня не отображается в окне static. Никак не могу понять, кнопка отображается, для static сделал аналогично, но не появляется ничего.

```
LabelClName db "STATIC"
LabelID dw 2
hwndLabel   HWND ?
TextLabel db "Empty",0=

WndProc proc hWnd:HWND, uMsg:UINT, wParam:WPARAM, lParam:LPARAM
    local rect:RECT
    local pt:POINT
    local pv:DWORD
    .IF uMsg==WM_DESTROY
        invoke PostQuitMessage,NULL
    .ELSEIF uMsg==WM_CREATE     ; Создание элементов 
        invoke CreateWindowEx, NULL, ADDR BtnClName, ADDR TextButton, WS_CHILD or BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON or WS_VISIBLE, 20, 20, 100, 50, hWnd, ButtonID, hInstance, 0
        mov hwndButton, eax
        invoke ShowWindow, hwndButton, SW_SHOWNORMAL
        invoke CreateWindowEx, NULL, ADDR LabelClName, ADDR TextLabel, WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE, 50, 20, 200, 50, hWnd, LabelID, hInstance, 0
        mov hwndLabel, eax
        invoke ShowWindow, hwndLabel, SW_SHOWNORMAL
    .ELSEIF uMsg==WM_COMMAND
        mov eax, wParam
        .IF ax==ButtonID
            shr eax, 16
            .IF ax==BN_CLICKED
                invoke CoInitialize, 0
                mov eax, hWnd
                mov bi.hwndOwner, eax
                invoke SHBrowseForFolder, ADDR bi
                mov pv, eax
            .ENDIF 
            ret
        .ENDIF
    .ELSE
        invoke DefWindowProc,hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam   
        ret
    .ENDIF
    xor eax,eax
    ret
WndProc endp
end start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что нет завершающего `0`. Должно быть так

```
LabelClName db "STATIC",0
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!)